# Reshaping Lists /Arrays

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have the following list :

```
initial_list =[[[1],[11]],[[2],[12]],[[3],[13]],[[4],[14]],[[5],[15]]]
```

and I want to converted the initial_list to the following list:

```
new_list = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you show us what you tried? Also, the operation you're asking for, is called (partial) flattening.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` and [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) like below:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> lst =[[[1],[11]],[[2],[12]],[[3],[13]],[[4],[14]],[[5],[15]]]
>>> list(map(list,map(chain.from_iterable,zip(*lst))))
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]

# for more explanation
>>> list(zip(*lst))
[([1], [2], [3], [4], [5]), ([11], [12], [13], [14], [15])]

>>> list(chain.from_iterable(list(zip(*lst))[0]))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `zip` and `iter`:

```
>>> initial_list = [[[1],[11]],[[2],[12]],[[3],[13]],[[4],[14]],[[5],[15]]]
>>> [list(map(next, map(iter, i))) for i in zip(*initial_list)]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]]
```